# Laptop speaker disappeared from sound settings

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

I am using Thinkpad T61 with Ubuntu 14.04. A few days ago I used my headphones for the first time after upgrading from 12.04 and got the sound to my headphones with not problem. However after I unplugged the headphones, I didn't get the sound back to the laptop speakers, and the output option for the laptop speakers disappeared from the Sound Settings. Is this possibly a bug in the new Ubuntu, or is it likely the problem with hardwares? Restarting the computer didn't help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to Plug the Headphones and Remove it Several Times, it Could Fix the Problem, I Encountered the Same few Days ago in Windows, that fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, Yousef's. I tried that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Wonder what's with your pc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch alsamixer in a terminal : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer

- Press F6 to select your main soundcard (not hdmi), scroll with arrow key to locate speaker fader and increase volume (up/down arrow) and/or unmute (m key)
- "auto-mute" and "independant" switch can make a bad effect too.

Comment: After playing with Alsamixer'settings and the sound came back (I played with several settings so I can't tell which one caused the problem). BTW, thanks a lot!

Comment: any failsafe way of getting this working? I want to at least have the sound be piped to earphones that don't work and know that it doesn't work. Right now it pipes to computer and I can hear it externally. Suddenly happens. Repeatedly happens.